# About z-index and positions

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm reading this article on z-index and got a question.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ylzj.png)

The z-index is like the layers, right? then layer(z-index) 1 should be on the top, two, three and on.

How come in this picture z-index 3 is above 2?

I saw that the two had different positions:

Div 3 is absolute so it goes out of context with everything else, but does that even apply to the 'layers'?

Answer (score -1):

Remember that z-index refers to elements being stacked on an imaginary z-axis which is perpendicular to the screen.

Here's the image from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context

[image]

*The z-index is like the layers, right?* Yes

*then layer(z-index) 1 should be on the top, two, three and on.* No - In the same stacking context, the element with the higher number z-index is on top.  Hence div 1 (z-index 5) is above (ie closer to the viewer) than div 3.

*How come in this picture z-index 3 is above 2?* Becase 3 is bigger than 2

*Div 3 is absolute so it goes out of context with everything else,* Not exactly. It itself is stacked with div1 and div2, those three divs are in the same stacking context. However, as div3 is positioned absolute, it forms a stacking context of its own and its children are stacked within that.